# Python for finding viable solar parcels close to power line

Tags: arcpy, proximity, parcel

I am currently working on a project for a solar company and we are interested in finding the closest parcels to a power line. For this project we have a few different shapefiles, parcels (dissolved by owner), power lines, and non-viable areas. Within the parcels feature class, we also have a field of "buildable area" with calculated percentages. From these features, we have different "tiers" of ranked criteria: 1 being, high percent of buildable area, short distance to power line, and here's the tricky part; cuts through the smallest number of parcels to get to the power line. We're also looking at a very large area (the entire state of NC).

For this reason, the company would like to use a Python script to run this analysis. I have a baseline idea for how to group the parcels and find the shortest path, but am really unsure how to go about this, as I have limited Python knowledge. Please let me know if you have any pointers, or how to go about this in a better way!

Attached below is the beginning idea of how to clump parcels to find the smallest parcel path to power line, but I'm unsure of how to add in the criteria tiers to this.

```
parcels_that_int_powerline_cond = select all dissolved by owner parcels that intersect powerline
list_of_parcels_that_intersect_IDs = []
with arcpy.da.searchcursor(parcels, [ID]) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
     list_of_parcels_that_intersect_IDs.append(row[0])


def find_next(parcel_featureclass, when_to_quit):
     parcel_thread_dict = {}
     parcel_IDs = []
     arcpy.da.searchcursor(parcel_featureclass, [ID]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
        parcel_IDs.append(row[0])
     for parcel_ID in parcel_IDs:
        feature_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer(parcel_featureclass, f"ID = {ID}")
        parcel_thread_dict[ID] = []
        parcel_count = 1
        while parcel_count <= when_to_quit:
           if feature_layer (meets optimal criteria):
              parcel_thread_dict[parcel_ID].append(parcel_ID)
           else:
           #continue searching
           current_parcel_int = select by location all parcels that intersect the current parcel
           find_next(current_parcel_int, 1)
           parcel_count += 1
     return parcel_thread_dict

 find_next(parcels_that_int_powerline_cond, 3)
```